# ASP.NET to AS/400 Communication Error

Tags: asp.net, ibm-midrange

When trying to access an AS/400 server from an ASP.NET webservice, I'm getting the following log message:

> 0x00000D98 0x00000001 10/14/2009
>   16:16:08.734375 :
>   iDB2ConnectionFailedException(9119245).Void
>   .ctor(System.String) :
>   iDB2ConnectionFailedException thrown
>   0x00000D98 0x00000001 10/14/2009
>   16:16:08.750000 :
>   iDB2ErrorCollection(14964341).Void
>   Add(IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Error) :
>   MESSAGE: The connection cannot be
>   opened because an error occurred.
>   MESSAGE DETAILS: A system policy has
>   been set preventing connections to a
>   data source through this provider.
>   MESSAGE CODE: 0

Note:  The user can ping the AS/400 from the webserver.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've never run into this situation myself, but I found a post on a different message board that may help.  It's at: http://forums.systeminetwork.com/isnetforums/showthread.php?t=48786

To summarize, the individual with the problem had to go into iSeries navigator and customize the setting in application administration.  To access application administration, start iSeries navigator and connect with a security officer profile.  Then right-click on your system and choose application administration.  Select the Client Applications tab.  Navigate to ODBC support and click on customize.  See if the user in question is blocked.

Here is a link to the IBM iSeries Infocenter for V5R4's documentation on application administration.  It may help to review it before trying to change anything: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaj3/rzaj3overview.htm

Here is a really good Four Hundred Guru article on application administration: http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg070809-story03.html

Granted, this only helps if the iSeries application administration settings are such that ODBC is blocked for this user.  There could very well be other Windows system policies that are blocking access to the iSeries data source.  In which case, this answer will not help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

being able to ping the server and being able to connect to a database service are two different things. Have you checked the policies and permissions on the AS/400?

Comment: We looked at the policies a bit on the AS/400 but didn't see anything out of the ordinary.  Can you point me in right direction as to what policy/permissions to look in to?